# How can i make a textedit field with both Decimal and Signed?

Tags: android

there is a XML TextEdit Field which has to has a decimal point and a sign before the number and the modes that i know are:

```
number : which takes numbers only,no decimal point or sign.
numberDecimal : which takes numbers and decimal point,no sign.
numberSigned : which takes numbers and a sign,no decimal point.
```

so i want the last two modes together somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this approach in your **xml layout** file

```
android:inputType="numberDecimal|numberSigned"
```